# Howto disable the tiny window menu buttons and just show the windowtoolbar (like in older versions of eclipse)

Tags: eclipse

Can anyone tell me what the windowitems in the Eclipse views encircled in red in the screenshot below are called? And more importantly, how to disable the use of them and just show the toolbar buttons of the view. In older versions of Eclipse the toolbar would just be shown instead of this tiny button to unhide the toolbar.

[screenshot of Eclipse with window menubuttons encircled in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdxi.jpg)

Comment: Those are the minimize / maximize items which have always been there. You should still be getting the view toolbars as well.

Comment: The buttons shown are not the minimize and maximize items, they are the 'show the toolbar' and 'minimize the view' buttons. The complete toolbar is only shown after you hover over/or click on the left item of the two (the tiny button). After that the usual buttons appear, first the specific toolbar buttons for this view and after them the View menu, Minimize, Maximize buttons.

Comment: If that is the case this is not standard Eclipse.